# Refreshing content in a partial view results in partial view duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to refreshing content inside a partial view on button click using jQuery ajax, but it's not working and all i'm getting is a duplicated partial view. Same partial view rendered twice in the pop up.

Here is my index.cshtml which contains the pop which i'm trying to update on clicking a button inside the pop up.

```
<div id="divAddSchedule" class="overlay_form" style="display:none;">
@{ Response<ScheduleType>response = new Response<ScheduleType>(); 
   Html.Partial("AddScheduleType", response);
 }
</div>
```

And here is the `AddScheduleType` partial view cshtml

```
    <a href="#" class="pop-close" title="close" onclick="ClosePopup()"></a>
<div class="popup-wrap edit-insitute add-user">
    <h2 id="popupTitle"></h2>

    <label for="rdResident">Resident</label>
    <input type="radio" id="rdResident" />
    <label for="rdAttending">Attending</label>
    <input type="radio" id="rdAttending" />

    <br clear="all" />
    <div id="divTypeList">

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="edit popuptable" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
            @{ if (Model.DataList != null && Model.DataList.Count > 0) { foreach (var sch in Model.DataList) {
            <tr>
                <td class="lblForTd" width="250px">@sch.Name
                </td>

                <td class="lblForTd" width="250px">@sch.Description
                </td>
            </tr>
            } } }
        </table>
        <br clear="all" />

        <div>
            <label>
                Schedule Type Name
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="txtScheduleName" />
            <label>
                Description
            </label>
            <textarea id="txtDescription"></textarea>
            <a id="btnAddScheduleType" href="#" onclick="AddScheduleType();">Add
        </a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And here is the partial view controller which is called both on doing the pop up and also on button click to add new content into the existing list.

```
public PartialViewResult AddScheduleType(string name, string description)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Response<ScheduleType> response = new Response<ScheduleType>();

        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Description");



        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "Hari";
            dr["Description"] = "New kid on the block";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        }

        IList<ScheduleType> instList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
                    new ScheduleType
                    {
                        Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
                        Description = row.Field<string>("Description")
                    }).ToList();

        if (name != null && description != null)
        {
            ScheduleType obj = new ScheduleType();
            obj.Name = name;
            obj.Description = description;

            instList.Add(obj);
        }

        response.DataList = instList;

        return PartialView("AddScheduleType", response);
```

And here is the jQuery AJAX call to update the partial view list

```
    function AddScheduleType() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Users/AddScheduleType',
        data: {
            name: $('#txtScheduleName').val(),
            description: $('#txtDescription').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divTypeList').html(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('An Error occurred while processing the request.');
        }
    });
}
```

Would be helpful if any one can point out what may be going wrong.

Comment: It might be useful to see this ajax request as well

Comment: check the resonse in cosole what html is coming?

Comment: empty the div before inserting the data `$('#divTypeList').html("");` `$('#divTypeList').html(data);`

Comment: ``.html()`` replaces the html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are replacing the content on the wrong div.

```
$('#divTypeList').html(data);
```

Should be

```
$('#divAddSchedule').html(data);
```

You are effectively nesting the addscheduletype within istself on each subsequent call